# Error when generating PKCS10 request on android

Tags: android, eclipse, certificate

I'm trying to generate PKCS10 request as follows(it is working on PC)

```
package exam.blowfishcipher;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
//import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;

import android.os.Environment;
import chapter6.PKCS10ExtensionExample;



public class PKCS10Generater
{
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateRequest(
        KeyPair pair)
        throws Exception

        {           
         return new PKCS10CertificationRequest(
                 "SHA256withRSA",
                 new X500Principal("CN=Test CA Certificate"),
                 //new X500Principal("CN=end"),
                 pair.getPublic(),
                 null,
                 pair.getPrivate());
        }

public static void pemEncodeToFile(String filename, Object obj, char[] password) throws Exception{
    PEMWriter pw = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
       if (password != null && password.length > 0) {
           pw.writeObject(obj, "DESEDE", password, new SecureRandom());
       } else {
           pw.writeObject(obj);
       }
       pw.flush();
       pw.close();
}

public static void reqGen() throws Exception
{
    //create the keys
    /*
    KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    //KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance()

    kpGen.initialize(512, chapter4.Utils.createFixedRandom());

    KeyPair pair=kpGen.generateKeyPair();
    */
    //PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateRequest(pair);

    KeyPair pair = chapter8.Utils.generateRSAKeyPair();
    //PKCS10CertificationRequest request = PKCS10ExtensionExample.generateRequest(pair);
    PKCS10CertificationRequest request = PKCS10ExtensionExample.generateRequest(pair);
    //System.out.println(request);
    //KeyPair pair = chapter6.Utils.generateRSAKeyPair();
    //PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateRequest(pair);




    pemEncodeToFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"pkcs10.req", request, null);
    PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    pemWrt.writeObject(request);
    pemWrt.close();

    /////////////////writing private key
    //PEMWriter pemWrt1 = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    //pemWrt1.writeObject(pair.getPrivate());
    //pemEncodeToFile("userPrivate.key", pair.getPrivate(), null);
    //pemWrt1.close();
    /////
    /////

    ////
    //FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("pkcs10.req");
    //fOut.write((request.getEncoded()));
    //fOut.write(sw.toString());
    //fOut.close();
    //pemWrt.close();


}
```

}

and error message from console output is as follows

***[2013-01-31 02:15:05 - BlowfishCipher] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.class":***

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2013-01-31 02:15:05 - BlowfishCipher] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-01-31 02:15:05 - BlowfishCipher] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I don't know why the codes not wort properly on android...

Comment: Use `SpongyCastle` instead of `BouncyCastle` on Android

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem;

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project;

your package  conflict with android.jar ;